# Positioning text and image as centered horizontally using position: relative

Tags: html, css, css-position

I was wondering how I can position the text centered horizontally. Centered horizontally with the image. I do not want to use the `position: absolute` attribute. This is because the length of the right and left text can change and to have an absolute attribute, you need a fixed width/size.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.right-text {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/VXlnn8a.png");
}

.left-text {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-text">Right</div><div class="icon"></div><div class="left-text">Left</div>
```

Comment: you can add text-align:center; to the css of the body
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align:center;
    }

Comment: I think you need vertical centre for content left and right with image

Comment: @HUSSAIN `text-align: center` centers text vertically.

Comment: @Alex i just google it to confirm, text-align: center is use to center text horizontally while i think you need to align it center vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox to align items horizontally center by adding below code to the parent `div`

```
.parent{
   display:flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

This is the running Snippet of your code having this changes

```css
   

    

    body{
           padding: 0;
           margin: 0;
           font-family: arial;
        }  
.content{
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
    }

.right-text {
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    .icon {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        background: url("https://i.imgur.com/VXlnn8a.png");
    }

.left-text {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="content">
           <div class="right-text">Right</div>
           <div class="icon"></div>
           <div class="left-text">Left</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The above code snippet not working horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply add a flexbox container and set its property align-items to center.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="right-text">Right</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="left-text">Left</div>
</div>
```

And this is the class container:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: You mis-understood the question. Not what I am asking for

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want vertical align here is the updated snippet

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.right-text {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/VXlnn8a.png");
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.left-text {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-text">Right</div><div class="icon"></div><div class="left-text">Left</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the position of the image. So only changing the text positon

Comment: Yes instead of specifying `top` at image class use the property in both `.left-text` and `.right-text` instead of positive use negative value in case of text . Only additional property i have given below 

`.right-text { top: -10px; } .left-text { top: -10px; } `

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to wrap your `right-text`, `icon` and `left-text` element in `childContainer` and then wrap your `childContainer` element in `parentContainer` wrap.

```
<div class="parentContainer">
  <div class="childContainer">
    <div class="right-text">Right</div><div class="icon"></div><div class="left-text">Left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next, you have to apply `FlexBox` with **center** `justify-content` and `align-items` value and you also need to add `height: 100vh`. Mentioned changes are applied on a below code snippet. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.right-text {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/VXlnn8a.png");
}

.left-text {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.parentContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentContainer">
  <div class="childContainer">
    <div class="right-text">Right</div><div class="icon"></div><div class="left-text">Left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```